# Is the snapshot of the last commit of rebase and a merge are the same?

Tags: git

I'm a newbie learner in Git. I'm reading the book at [https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2] and now i'm on the chapter "3.6 Rebasing".

This chapter has a point:

> Note that the snapshot pointed to by the final commit you end up with, whether it’s the last of the rebased commits for a rebase or the final merge commit after a merge, is the same snapshot – it’s only the history that is different.

I think it's not right in all cases. Let's look at a case below.

Assume we are at a commit `C0` on 2 branches `master` and `test`. And we have an empty `foo` text file.

Next, we check out the `master`, write a text `"line 1"` to `foo` and make a commit `C1`. Then we check out the `test`, also write a text `"line 1"` to `foo`, make a commit `C2`. After that, we remove the text `"line 1"` from foo, make a commit `C3`.

History now:

```
C0---C1 master
 \
  C2---C3 test-HEAD
```

Now we have 2 cases to move:

1. *Use the merging* by `git merge master`: Git take the merged result to `C4`. The content of `foo` now is `"line 1"`. History now:

   ```
   C0---C1 master
   |      \
   C2--C3--C4 test
   ```
2. *Use the rebasing* by `git rebase master`: the last commit after rebasing is `C3'`. The content of `foo` now is empty. History now:

   ```
   C0---C1 master
         \
          C2'---C3' test
   ```

You can see, the snapshot is pointed by `C4` and by `C3'` are not the same, because content of `foo` in `C4` is different with `foo` in `C3'`. So I think the quoted sentence above is not right in this case.

Am I have something wrong? Thank you.

P/s: I'm not very good in English, so please forgive me if have something not good in my writing.

Answer (score 1):

> Use the rebasing by git rebase master: the last commit after rebasing is C3'. The content of foo now is empty.

No. C2' tries to add "line1" to the file, but it already contains this line so you get a conflict. Depending on how you resolve the conflict the result may be different. If you decide to keep both "line1" lines (the one in C1, and the one you're adding in C2), then C3' will remove one of these lines (again, you'll get a conflict and it depends on how you resolve it), and you'll get "line1" as the content.

I think your mistake is to think that C3 and C3' correspond to the same snapshot. They don't: they correspond to the same patch, i.e. the same difference with respect to their parents.

Bottom-line: `rebase` may create more conflicts that `merge`, especially in cases where the history goes one way and cancels it later. When you don't have conflicts, the end result of `rebase` and `merge` must be the same.

Comment: I actually did the test and I found that when rebasing git is actually skipping the first revision from being cherry-picked... my assumption is that git notices that C2 and C1 are the same so no point in applying it. I reach the same conclusion you do, Matthieu, in this case git is being "tricked" because of having C2 and C1 being the same change "and" also having C3 and C0 with the same content. Can you try with a real example, @Messi so that you can see that the end result (in terms of the trees) are the same for both processes?

Comment: Hmm, indeed, in this case C1 and C2 correspond to the same patch, hence `git rebase` will skip C2 when applying. IOW, C2' won't be there. Technically, it's skipped because it has the same patch-id.

Comment: I did the rebasing on terminal, and yes, Git skip the C2'; and then, Git go to C3' to remove "line 1" and finally the `foo` file is empty. And it's different with C4 - `foo` contains "line 1". So the snapshot pointed to by the last commit of rebase way and merge way is not always the same?